# Segmentation fault in SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite, segmentation-fault

Code in my DataBase.cpp file:

```
#include "DataBase.h"
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>
bool CanClose(void)
{
    sqlite3 *Sqlite;
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;
    char *result;
    if(sqlite3_open("SysConfig",&Sqlite)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
       sqlite3_prepare(Sqlite,"SELECT config_value FROM configuration WHERE config_id = 1;",-1,&sqlstmt,NULL);
       sqlite3_step(sqlstmt);
       result = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt,0);
       sqlite3_close(Sqlite);
       if(strcmp(result,"YES")==1)    //Error Here
           return true;
       else
           return false;
    }
    else
    {
        wxMessageBox(_("Cannot Find System File!"),_("Error!"));
        sqlite3_close(Sqlite);
        return false;
    }
}
```

My program was behaving abruptly..
When I tried debuging it, the line indicated above (line 19) is giving some error as:

**program recieved signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.**

further dissasembly of the statement show error at a assembly instruction

`call 0x80500b0`

Have any idea what is the problem with the code?

Comment: That looks like C, not C++.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: I have to compile it with C++ because I am using this code with my wxWidgets code.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html says "If any of these routines are called after sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() or after sqlite3_step() has returned something other than SQLITE_ROW, the results are undefined.". You aren't checking the return value of `sqlite3_step`, so perhaps your query is returning some sort of error, and then `sqlite3_column_text` is returning an invalid pointer.

Comment: Just found that `sqlite3_prepare()` is unable to prepare the statement for execution.

Comment: Putting Some More checks revealed that `sqlite3_prepare()` is returning a **SQLITE_ERROR** where
`#define SQLITE_ERROR 1 /* SQL error or missing database */` But I have made sure that DataBase is present here.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to wxWidgets so removing its tag.

Answer (score 4):

## Reason for segfault

The [sqlite3 documentation for `sqlite3_column_text`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) says:

> If any of these routines are called [...] after `sqlite3_step()` has returned something other than `SQLITE_ROW`, the results are undefined."

You aren't checking the return value of `sqlite3_step`, so it seems your query is returning some sort of error, and then `sqlite3_column_text` is returning an invalid pointer.

## Debugging the SQL error

According to [the documentation for `prepare`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html):

> The `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` and `sqlite3_prepare16_v2()` interfaces are recommended for all new programs. The two older interfaces [including `sqlite3_prepare`, which you call] are retained for backwards compatibility, but their use is discouraged.
>
> [...]
>
> When an error occurs, sqlite3_step() will return one of the detailed error codes or extended error codes. The legacy behavior was that sqlite3_step() would only return a generic SQLITE_ERROR result code and the application would have to make a second call to sqlite3_reset() in order to find the underlying cause of the problem. With the "v2" prepare interfaces, the underlying reason for the error is returned immediately.

So if you switch to the newer interface, it should give a more informative message, rather than the generic `SQLITE_ERROR`.

You could also try using the `sqlite3` command-line program, which will directly tell you what the error is. Example session:

```
user@host:/path$ sqlite3 test.sqlite
sqlite> create table example ( id numeric primary key );
sqlite> select bogus from example;
Error: no such column: bogus
```

---

Incidentally, for standard C++ use `#include <cstring>` for `#include <string.h>` and `bool CanClose()` for `bool CanClose(void)`.